# How to append a column from another file to an existing file using awk?

Tags: bash, awk, append

My problem is the following: I have multiple tab separated files (A, B, C and D) each containing 40 columns of which the first 10 are always the same (all files also have the same number of rows). In order to have one file instead of four separate ones, I want to create a new file which contains the first 10 columns once (which are the same in all files) followed by column 25 of each file A, B, C and D since I'm not interested in the other columns.

So my output file should look like this:

column_1 column_2 column_3 .... column_9 column_10 column_25_A column_25_B column_25_C column_25_D

So far I was able to create a new file containing column_1 to column_10 using the following command:

```
awk -v FS='\t' -v OFS='\t' '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10}' file_A.txt > output_file.txt
```

However, I cannot manage to now append the desired columns from the other files. I've tried the paste command as well as this one:

```
awk -v FS='\t' -v OFS='\t' '{print $25}' file_A.txt >> output_file
```

The above command however gives me correct column I want to append to the output file if I omit the redirection.

What do I have to do in order to append the desired columns from one file to another using awk? Or is this not possible?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output. Make sure the example is **minimal** and so use, say, 5 or 6 fields per line instead of 25+.

Answer (score 2):

untested

```
$ paste <(cut -f1-10,25 fileA) <(cut -f25 fileB) <(cut -f25 fileC) <(cut -f25 fileD)
```